# Ruby multiple enumerables on one arg?

Tags: ruby

I was not aware you could do this in Ruby, can someone please give me an explanation on how this works, and is there a name for this? Like is he using multiple enums. on just nums? Need a decent explanation, as I'm still a newbie obviously.

This method is using splat, so you can give any amount of arguments example:

```
   mutual_factors(16,8,24) #=> [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

and it will give the common factors that work with all the arguments.

```
def mutual_factors(*nums)
    nums
        .map { |n| factors(n) }
        .inject(:&)
end

def factors(number)
    (1..number).select {|num| number % num == 0}
    end
```

Comment: It's unclear what "this" refers to in your question. Are asking about passing multiple values to one argument with splat? Based on comments below, might you be asking about [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)?

Comment: I'm asking how is he passing two enumerables into one variable at the same time without I clouding the variable in front of the two methods? I think the other guy explained it pretty well.

Comment: Yes sorry, I missed Method Chaining. Thanks so much. It's hard to understand something that you don't know how to Google lol.

Answer (score 4):

`factors` is easy to understand. Given a number, just computes the list of all common factors. Better algorithm do exist for this.

`mutual_factors` creates a common factor for every element that is provided and takes `intersection` among all the arrays. The [`&` operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/Array.html#method-i-26) is used for this. You can understand in this way.

```rb
(ins)irb(main):039:0> factors(10)
=> [1, 2, 5, 10]
(ins)irb(main):040:0> factors(20)
=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]
(ins)irb(main):041:0> factors(10) & factors(20)
=> [1, 2, 5, 10]
```

A explicit loop version which is more beginner friendly

```rb
def mutual_factors_explicit_looping(*nums)
  common_factor = nil
  nums.each do |num|
    common_factor = if common_factor.nil?
                      factors(num)
                    else
                      common_factor & factors(num)
                    end
  end
  common_factor
end
```

Comment: nums
        .map { |n| factors(n) }
        .inject(:&)                                       i mean this? is he calling both methods on just nums? All i have ever done is nums.map never have i done nums      .map . inject without using num.method ... Does that make since? How does that work

Comment: or is he doing nums.map.inject? The way it is written is what confuses me, not the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question has been answered so I would like to suggest an alternative way to compute the common factors that is generally more efficient than simply looping through values.

This will make use of the method [Prime#prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division).

Suppose we wish to get the factors of `360`. We find that

```
require 'prime'
```

```
arr = Prime.prime_division(720)
  #=> [[2, 4], [3, 2], [5, 1]]
```

This means that

```
720 = (2**4) * (3**2) * (5**1)
```

where `2`, `3`, and `5` are the prime divisors of `360`.

---

For convenience I will write

```
h = Prime.prime_division(720).to_h
  #=> {2=>4, 3=>2, 5=>1}
```

Similarly,

```
Prime.prime_division(2100).to_h
  #=> {2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>2, 7=>1}
```

meaning that

```
2100 = (2**2) * (3**1) * (5**2) * (7**1)
```

---

We know that every factor of both `720` and `2100` will equal

```
(2**w) * (3**x) * (5**y) * (7**z)
```

where

```
0 <= w <= [4, 2].min = 2
0 <= x <= [2, 1].min = 1
0 <= y <= [1, 2].min = 1
0 <= z <= [0, 1].min = 0
```

In other words, `2` may have a power of `0`, `1` or `2`, `3` may have powers of `0` or `1`, `5` may have a power of `0` or `1` and `7` must have a power of `0`, generating 12 common factors (`3*2*2*1`). The common factors are therefore the following. (I will disregard powers of `7` as zero is the only one.)

```
(2**0) * (3**0) * (5**0) #=  1
(2**0) * (3**1) * (5**0) #=  3
(2**0) * (3**0) * (5**1) #=  5
(2**0) * (3**1) * (5**1) #= 15

(2**1) * (3**0) * (5**0) #=  2
(2**1) * (3**1) * (5**0) #=  6
(2**1) * (3**0) * (5**1) #= 10
(2**1) * (3**1) * (5**1) #= 30

(2**2) * (3**0) * (5**0) #=  4
(2**2) * (3**1) * (5**0) #= 12
(2**2) * (3**0) * (5**1) #= 20
(2**2) * (3**1) * (5**1) #= 60
```

---

We can generate those factors as follows. First, define a helper method.

```
def factor(primes, powers)
  primes.zip(powers).reduce(1) { |tot,(pr,pow)| tot * (pr**pow) }
end
```

```
factor([2,3,5], [4,2,1])
  #=> 720
```

Next, for a given hash whose keys are primes and whose values are the maximum power, we can generate all factors of a number as follows.

```
def factors(h)
  primes = h.keys
  first, *rest = h.values.map { |v| (0..v).to_a }
  first.product(*rest).map { |powers| factor(primes, powers) }
end
```

```
factors({2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>1})
  #=> [1, 5, 3, 15, 2, 10, 6, 30, 4, 20, 12, 60]
```

---

It remains to put this all together.

```
def common_factors(first, *rest)
  factors(rest.each_with_object(Prime.prime_division(first).to_h) do |n,h|
    g = Prime.prime_division(n).to_h
    g.keys.each { |k| h[k] = (h.key?(k) ? [h[k], g[k]].min : 0) }
  end)
end
```

```
common_factors(720, 2100)
  #=> [1, 5, 3, 15, 2, 10, 6, 30, 4, 20, 12, 60]
```

```
common_factors(720, 2100, 90)
  #=> [1, 5, 3, 15, 2, 10, 6, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

`#inject` takes an `Enumerable` object and "injects" an operation between the elements.

Consider a simple example:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):002:0> a.inject { |a, b| a + b }
=> 10
irb(main):003:0> a.inject { |a, b| a * b }
=> 24
irb(main):004:0> a.inject(:+)
=> 10
irb(main):005:0> a.inject(:*)
=> 24
```

We know `factors(8)`, `factors(6)`, and `factors(16)` give us `[1, 2, 4, 8]`, `[1, 2, 3, 6]`, and `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]` respectively.

So `[8, 6, 16].map { |x| factors x }` gives us `[[1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]]`. If we inject `:&` into that, we have the equivalent of:

```
([1, 2, 4, 8] & [1, 2, 3, 6]) & [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

Which reduces to:

```
[1, 2] & [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

And then to:

```
[1, 2]
```